emacs eww command do not render libmicrohttpd html
i write a c++ http server based on libmicrohttpd, and i can open the link with chrome, the result is OK.
when i open the link with emacs eww, the result is raw html.
i saved the html in file, and open it with eww-open-file, emacs could render the html.
emacs version: GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.14) of 2020-03-26, modified by Debian
the html is below
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">
<title>HOMEPAGE</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<a href="/monitor">Monitor-test</a><br>
<a href="/notknow">Notknow</a><br>
<a href="/datanodeinfo">datanodeinfo</a><br>
<a href="/ls">ls</a><br>
</body>
</html>



i use edeug-function to debug eww-render, find out it use text/plain to render the result. so i set the return header to text/html, and the render result is ok.

I think the real question is: Why would anything have rendered a text/plain response as if it were HTML? You might want to raise a bug report for Chrome about that.
